# python Pool map multiple arguments - list and variable as input

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, arguments, pool

I would like to multiprocess a function (see below)

```
def func(c):
    time =  time
    list = [c, time]
    another_func(list)
```

I run this above function as follows:

```
p = multiprocess.Pool()
p.map(func, cust, chunksize=1)
p.close()
p.join()
```

cust is a list of strings like

```
cust = ['c1', 'c2', ...]
```

Now my question is it possible to get the time variable into the p.map like

```
p.map(func, cust, time, chunksize=1)
```

I have searched multiple topics here but I did not find a matching topic.

Thx for any help/hints!

Comment: Pass a tuple of the values ;)

Comment: can you show the value of variable `time` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap):

```
def func(c, time):
    my_list = [c, time]
    another_func(my_list)


p.starmap(func, [(c, time) for c in cust], chunksize=1)
```

even better:

```
p.map(another_func, [[c, time] for c in cust], chunksize=1)
```